# Class diagram for a class creating another class

Tags: uml

If class `Admin` job is to create another class `Lecturer`, what relation should i put between them
and should GUI include into class diagram

[image]

(Image with better resolution:  http://postimg.org/image/rxnlbplpz/)

Am i doing this right?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @artm click on the link

Comment: Both classes should be defined in your model. But do not have to be displayed on class diagram. UML Tools allow to define classes without visual representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation you may use is

> Source: [uml-diagrams.org: Dependency in UML](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage)
>
> [image]

For one example of it's use in UML class diagram see [uml-diagrams.org: Sentinel HASP Classes of Aladdin Package](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-licensing-class-diagram-example.html?context=cls-examples)

For an example of [object creation message](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#create) (`<<create>>`) in UML sequence diagram see [uml-diagrams.org: Submit Comments to Pluck](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html#pluck-comments)

You can mix whatever set of classes coming from whichever [package/layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture) in your UML class diagram (including GUI classes) freely. It is just a matter of taste and matter of what you want to show/emphasize.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define "dynamic" creation of instance of class using "new" message in sequence diagram. Creation message should be drawn from lifeline representing Admin to lifeline which represent Lecturer. "New" message ends at lifeline header symbol of target (created) instance. For more details see UML Superstructure document section interactions.
Similar operation of creation is possible to define in Activity diagram using special action CreateObjectAction. See UML Superstructure Action model section.

Static relation for creation is not standard UML construction.

Comment: Does that mean i dont need to put Admin Class into class diagram since its is creation